# How do I modify Upsert key for a snowflake output in Upsolver

Tags: sqlake, upsolver

Is it possible to add an Upsert key to an existing output or change the Upsert key for an existing output without creating a new output?

This is all very hypothetical right now! Since this is new data and a lot of the schemas have been changing during design phases, I just want to get ahead of any problems we might have.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to update the Upsert keys for an existing output in Upsolver. Best way to do handle this is to create a new snowflake table (or delete existing data and keep same table), duplicate your output, change your Upsert key and replay